# Can't add suburb to Facebook page info

Tags: facebook, location

Our business is located in a suburb of Perth, Western Australia.

If we use Perth as the City/town, we receive a message:

> We couldn't determine the location from the provided address. Make
>   sure to enter a valid address.

If we try and enter our suburb in City/town, it is not found in the auto-populate ajax feature, and we can't save this value - it disappears when the cursor leaves the City/town field.

I have asked a colleague to check-in on Facebook on her iPhone, and asked her to enter our suburb as the location, which wasn't found, but we clicked "Add Location", and saved the location, but 3 days later this location is still not found when we edit our page's info.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this and it works!  If you are getting this error message when you edit your address: "We couldn't determine the location from the provided address. Make sure to enter a valid address."

I took the "Court" away from the end of the street address and saved the page, I then got an error message with a map and I was able to drag the pin onto the correct address.  Saved the page again and viola! My page turned into a check-in place.

Comment: With my FB page, the issue is with the town, not the street, and this method does not work the same way, unfortunately.